# "Kind regards" in Russian

Tags: лексикон

I have been looking around in the net, and I have several options come up, so I better ask those who know. Is "С уважением" a proper end of a mail with equivelant to kind regards or is it something else altogether?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"С уважением" literally - 'with respect'. It's a proper end of a mail, but you need to add your name to the end of the sentence: "С уважением, Албан."
As noted by  **Artemix**, "С уважением" can be used for any business/official letters.

You can also end the letter with such phrases: "Всего наилучшего!", "С наилучшими пожеланиями! [Author's name]."

Comment: Note: "С уважением" can be used for any business/official letters.

Comment: "С уважением" can be used without your name, but it makes the sentence a bit more... agressive? I frequently use it when I want to sound very polite and make my conversation partner angry at the same time (without being too open with such intent).

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy: so you say without the name is something similar to the British English telling off in the middle of a conversation, "Good Day, sir."?

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae I would be glad to answer, but I am no expert of British English.

Answer (score -2):

For something perhaps a bit closer to the "feel" of "kind regards" (to me «с уважением» feels more like "yours faithfully" or even the archaic "your obedient servant"), consider «с сердечным приветом,...» "with heart-felt greetings,....".  «С горячим приветом» would be another alternative, but that might be a bit strong.

Comment: For those down-ticking my choices, I'll just mention that Smirnitskij ( *Русско-aнглийский Словарь*, стр. 482; 13-ое изд. (1985);  Москва «Русский Язык») likes them.

Comment: Не хочу показаться невежливым, но в слове «привет» третья буква — и.

Comment: Спасибо большое; Андрей!  Сделать такую ошибочку и *два* раза -- лицо мое красно от смущения.